# CouchDB / Cloudant get another object using reference

Tags: json, couchdb, cloudant

We are using two objects: Employee and Company

In Employee object contains a reference to Company (idcompany). How can I get the Employee object with the Company fields too? (Using a view or search index)

Example:

**employee**
{
"name":"test",
"idcompany":"4a70356d1a99260f3b9fd565a10e5ece",
"objecttype":"employee"
}

**company**
{
"id":"4a70356d1a99260f3b9fd565a10e5ece",
"name":"test",
"objecttype":"company"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [Join With Views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/joins.html) proposal

You can define view with the following map function

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.idcompany) {
  emit(doc._id, {"_id":doc.idcompany});
  }
}
```

Then retrieve the view values using the include_docs=true param. You will get the key that you defined in the emit function, joined with the company document.